# Lacinia and re-graph incompatible headers

Tags: clojure, graphql, clojurescript, luminus

I'm using the last available lacinia version: "0.36.0-alpha-3" with Luminus (Ring+reitit), but this version asks for a specific header:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:3000/api/graphql' -X POST --data "{test_by_id(id: 5) { title } }" -H 'Content-Type: application/graphql'
```

that request works fine, but without "'Content-Type: application/graphql'" the request wouldn't work. So I need to define my re-graph init vector like:

```
  [::re-graph/init
    {:ws-url                  nil 
     :http-url                "http://localhost:3000/api/graphql"
     :http-parameters         {:with-credentials? false
                               :headers {"Content-Type" "application/graphql"}
                               }
     :ws-reconnect-timeout    nil
     :resume-subscriptions?   false   
     :connection-init-payload {}}]
```

but putting that header makes re-graph unable to work properly:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Failed to parse GraphQL query.","extensions":{"errors":[{"locations":[{"line":1,"column":null}],"message":"mismatched input '\"query\"' expecting {'query', 'mutation', 'subscription',
```

it looks like re-graph sends and receives data using "application/json" header, so lacinia asks for some type of header but re-graph can't work with that option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I think I got a solution for it. re-frame requests follows the Apollo [Specification](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data/#queries-with-variables), as stated by @aarkerio. Here is the code to keep the original endpoint working with the origina specification, and allow it to respond to re-frame requests. This will make the endpoint respond to Graphiql request (from your http://localhost:3000/graphiql route), and re-graph ones. Any comments or corrections are welcomed.

Replace the original function set on the `/graphql` route on `src/clj/mem_learning/routes/services.clj`:

```
["/graphql" {:post graphql-call}
```

Add the `graphql-call` function on that same file:

```
(defn graphql-call [req]
  (let [body (:body-params req)
        content-type (keyword (get-in req [:headers "content-type"]))]
    (case content-type
          :application/json (ok (graphql/execute-request-re-graph body))
          :application/graphql (ok (graphql/execute-request (-> req :body slurp))))))
```

add the `execute-request-re-graph` to the `src/clj/mem_learning/routes/services/graphql.clj` file:

```
(defn execute-request-re-graph
  "execute request with re-graph/apollo format"
  [{:keys [variables query context]}]
  (lacinia/execute compiled-schema query variables context)))
```

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER:**

It looks that Luminus creates a middleware configuration:

```
(defn service-routes []
  ["/api"
   {:coercion spec-coercion/coercion
    :muuntaja formats/instance
    :swagger {:id ::api}
    :middleware [;; query-params & form-params
             parameters/parameters-middleware
             ;; content-negotiation
             muuntaja/format-negotiate-middleware
             ;; encoding response body
             muuntaja/format-response-middleware
             ;; exception handling
             exception/exception-middleware
             ;; decoding request body
             muuntaja/format-request-middleware
             ;; coercing response bodys
             coercion/coerce-response-middleware
             ;; coercing request parameters
             coercion/coerce-request-middleware
             ;; multipart
             multipart/multipart-middleware
             ]}
```

commenting the line "muuntaja/format-negotiate-middleware" makes the "application/json" call possible.

**SECOND UPDATE (four hours later)**

Ok, that muuntaja middleware thing was not the problem at all, the real problem is that curl send the data with the format:

```
{ test_by_id(id: 7, archived: false) { title } }
```

meanwhile re-graph uses:

```
{"query":"query { test_by_id(id: 7, archived: false) { title } }","variables":null}
```

this is a normal java string btw not a data structure, so we need to do some changes, first a new function:

```
(defn graphql-call [req]
  (let [body       (-> req :body slurp)
    full-query (json/read-str body :key-fn keyword)
    _          (log/info (str ">>>  **** full-query >>>>> " full-query))]
(ok (graphql/execute-request full-query))))
```

we set the function:

```
["/graphql" {:post graphql-call}]
```

and in *my_app.routes.services.graphql* file:

```
(defn execute-request [{:keys [variables query context]}]
  (json/write-str (lacinia/execute compiled-schema query variables context)))
```

and now re-graph works!

(also now I can send and use variables in GraphQL)

It's necessary to set:

```
 :http-parameters         {:with-credentials? false
                           :oauth-token "ah4rdSecr3t"
                           :headers {"Content-Type" "application/graphql"}
```

btw. Also, maybe it's better:

```
(lacinia/execute compiled-schema query variables context)
```

than:

```
(json/write-str (lacinia/execute compiled-schema query variables context))
```

because it interferes with re-graph importing the data already as a native ClojureScript map.